# I need a new keyboard, and I'd like one that replicates the feel of the failed Apple butterfly keyboards

Tags: keyboards

I need a new keyboard. I'd like one for under 75$ that feels like the Apple butterfly keyboards that were found on the 2015-2016 MacBooks. I know that those keyboards were hated and were prone to failure, but I personally thought they felt amazing. I guess what I'm looking for is a USB keyboard that requires little force and had very, very low travel while still feeling good to type on. I don't care about backlight, but I'd prefer if it was wired, unless there is no option for wired. The keyboard does not need to use the butterfly design, I don't care about that. All I want is a keyboard that feels like Apple's butterfly keyboard. It also needs to be Windows compatible.

Answer (score 1):

All I know the external keyboard with USB or wireless never have a butterfly-key design. Because that was exclusively designed for Apple? Dunno but probably because of the patent.

The smooth feeling of the laptop keyboard can be replaced by an external keyboard if the keyboard is very cheap.

You can search at your local shop that looks like this:

[image: keyboard]

But keep in mind because this is usually using only carbon pad switch the quality isn't the same at all..

Answer (score 0):

The original (& now unfortunately discontinued) Apple A1243 Wired Aluminium Keyboard is similar in feel, but considerably superior to the butterfly laptop keyboards mechanically. Buying second hand is not much of a risk, because of their durability.

[image]

You can find them on such as eBay for as little as $£€ 35 or so (when they were first discontinued the prices rocketed to about £140, matching the price of a brand new wireless one, but fortunately the panic is over & prices have dropped again.)

Unless you manage to damage it by accident (they are to all intents & purposes not repairable if you water-spill etc), I'd expect one to stand up to constant use for perhaps a decade, by which time it will still work just fine, but some of the letters will have worn off ;)

The oldest one still in use here is now over a decade old (from a 2008 Mac Pro), still as good as when it was new. We replaced one after a water spill & one after it was no longer legible - 10 hours a day for 10 years will do that;) though we still keep it as a spare.